# How do I select the TR here?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, parent

Here is my code, setWord is 1985:

```
$("td:contains(" + setWord + ")").css("textDecoration", "underline");
```

I thought this would do the trick:

```
$("td").not(":contains(" + setWord + ")").parent().css("backgroundColor", "red");
```

But apparently not. I'm just trying to select that TD's parent TR

```
<tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>03/09/1985</td>
            <td>Red</td>
            <td>Australia</td>
            <td>$ Dollars</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Dave</td>
            <td>01/01/1987</td>
            <td>Blue</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>&pound; Pounds</td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: _"I'm just trying to select that TD's parent TR"_ - Which TD? You're using `.not()`, so that will select TDs that do _not_ contain the `setWord`...

Comment: Works for me as you have it: http://jsfiddle.net/HtJdS/ (which will select both `<tr>` since both contain `<td>` _not_ including setWord)

Comment: Why are you doing DOM selection based on text content? Can't you provide attributes to the elements so that you have something more suitable for selection? You could add a `data-` attribute to each `tr` that contains the year you're trying to select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the idea is to change the background of all rows that do not contain the `setWord` "1985" then try this:

```
$("tr").not(":contains(" + setWord + ")").css("backgroundColor", "red");
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kwH6L/

If the idea is to change the background of rows that *do* contain the `setWord` then try this:

```
$("td:contains(" + setWord + ")").parent().css("backgroundColor", "red");
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kwH6L/1/

The problem with the code you showed:

```
$("td").not(":contains(" + setWord + ")").parent().css("backgroundColor", "red");
```

...is that you start by selecting *all* TD elements, then remove the ones that contain the `setWord`, but that still selects at least some TD elements in every row. So then when you get the `.parent()` of the selected TDs you get every TR element...

Comment: I pasted the top line wrong, it's fixed now, but I didn't realise I could search in just the TR, this fixed it, thanks: